# Arithmetic operation issue in bash script | invalid arithmetic operator

Tags: bash, arithmetic

From a bash script I am downloading a file from a server using `curl` call. Now I want to check if the file is fully downloaded. For this I am comparing the size of downloaded file and `Content-Length` header. Although both are equal I am getting below error:

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Part of bash script:

```
remote_size=$(curl -kI "${HEADERS[@]}" "$url" | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}')
                local_size=$(stat --format=%s "$dest/$file")
                if (( remote_size == local_size )); then
                        echo "File is complete" >&2
                elif (( remote_size > local_size )); then
                        echo "Download is incomplete" >&2
                elif (( remote_size < local_size )); then
                        echo "Remote file shrunk -- probably should delete local and start over" >&2
                fi
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885503/check-if-curl-incremental-continue-at-download-is-successful/37885681?

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am testing on ubuntu (on WSL), but the script will finally be part of Linux on an embedded platform. Please let me know if any info is missing

Comment: The misplaced `)` seems like a CR/LF issue. Remove the `$'\r'` from the value.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @terdon, currently I am testing on ubuntu (on WSL), but the script will finally be part of Linux on an embedded platform..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ curl -sI https://google.com | sed -n '/content-length/l'
content-length: 220\r$
```

See the carriage-return (aka `CR`, `\r`, `^M`) at the end of the line (`$` is `sed`'s way to represent the end of the line). HTTP headers [are delimited with CRLF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4), while the Unix line delimiter is LF.

Also [using unsanitised data in arithmetic expressions in bash and other Korn-like shells is a command injection vulnerability](/q/172103), all the more a problem here that you used the `-k` aka `--insecure` option allowing MitM attackers to inject arbitrary headers in responses.

On a GNU system, you can use:

```
local_size=$(stat -Lc %s -- "$dest/$file") || die
remote_size=$(curl -sI -- "$url" | LC_ALL=C grep -Piom1 '^content-length:\s*\K\d+') ||
  die "No content-length"
case $((local_size - remote_size)) in
  (0) echo same;;
  (-*) echo remote bigger;;
  (*) echo local bigger;;
esac
```

By only returning what `\d+` matches in the C locale, we make sure `remote_size` only contains decimal ASCII  digits, removing the ACE vulnerability.

A standard equivalent of that GNU `grep` command could be:

```
LC_ALL=C sed '/^[Cc][Oo][Nn][Tt][Ee][Nn][Tt]-[Ll][Ee][Nn][Gg][Tt][Hh]:[[:space:]]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/!d;s//\1/;q'
```

With the caveat that if the header is not found, it wouldn't return a *false* exit status like `grep` does so you'd need an additional check for `[ -n "$remote_size" ]`.

`die` above could be:

```
die() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}
```

(adapt to whatever logging mechanism you want to use).

Also note that though that would be very unlikely in practice, it's possible for headers to be folded. For instance, the content-length header could be returned as:

```
Content-Length:<CR>
 123456<CR>
```

One way to extract the header value is to use `formail` which is a tool designed to work with RFC822 headers:

```
remote_size=$(curl... | formail -zcx content-length -U content-length)
```

With `-U content-length`, if there's more than one `Content-Length`  header, it's the last one that is returned. Change `-U` to `-u` to return the first like with `grep -m1` above.

You'll still want to sanitise the result  or use `[`'s (not `[[...]]`'s!) `-lt`/`-eq`/`-gt` operators instead of `((...))` to avoid the ACE vulnerabilities.

With `curl` 7.84.0 or newer, you can also get `curl` to give you the value of that header directly with:

```
remote_size=$(curl -w '%header{content-length}' -sIo /dev/null -- "$url") || die
```

Through testing, I find that

- if there are several occurrences of the header, it will return the value for the first one only
- it will complain if the value doesn't start with a digit optionally preceded with a `+`, but still needs to be sanitised as whatever characters there are after that are passed along.
- it does support folded headers, but rejects a content-length whose first line has an empty value.

Comment: Hello @Stéphane Chazelas, I have `busybox grep` and `-P` is not supported. So, `grep -Piom1 '^content-length:\s*\K\d+'` produces error. Also tried with `-E` option, but no result.. How can I make this work with busybox?

Comment: Use `curl -w '%header{content-length}' -sIo /dev/null -- "$url"` if you have a recent-enough version of `curl`

Comment: Sadly, the curl version is `curl 7.58.0`

Comment: @Preeti See edit.

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane Chazelas